# Javascript: Using Regex to detect a numeral format

Tags: javascript, regex, string, format, roman-numerals

I have a string like this:

> Congratulation to {0} who won {1}{2:#,##0.##} in {3}

And the array data like this:

> ["Join", "USD", 10000, "Poker round 10"];

I wrote a function to format that string, but my problem is numeral format can not be detected.

```js
String.prototype.format = function (arg) {
    var rep_fn = undefined;

    if (typeof arg == "object") {
        rep_fn = function (m, k) { return arg[k]; };
    }
    else {
        var args = arguments;
        rep_fn = function (m, k) { return args[parseInt(k)]; };
    }

    return this.replace(/\{(\w+)\}/g, rep_fn);
};


var fm = "Congratulation to {0} who won {1} {2:#,##0.##} in {3}";
var data = ["Join", "USD", 10000, "Poker round 10"];
console.log(fm.format(data));
```

Current result:

> Congratulation to Join who won USD {2:#,##0.##} in Poker game round 10

Expect:

> Congratulation to Join who won USD 10,000.00 in Poker game round 10

Anyone have ideal to help me solve it?
Many thanks.

Comment: else block never executed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot of redundant code. You dont need `var args = arguments`. Your else block is never execurted, because the if is always true.

```js
String.prototype.format = function (arg) {
    for (let i = 0; i < arg.length; i++) {
        if (typeof arg[i] == "number") {
           arg[i] = arg[i].toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '$1,') + ".00";
        }
    }
   return this.replace(/\{(\w+)\}/g, (m,k) => arg[k]);
};


var fm = "Congratulation to {0} who won {1} {2} in {3}";
var data = ["Join", "USD", 10000, "Poker round 10"];
console.log(fm.format(data));
```